# Is a type that allows a collection string values considered clean code?

Tags: typescript

I have a type that looks like this:

```
type Foo = "PrivateWallet" | "JointWallet" | "CorporationWallet" | "JuniorWallet";
```

In JS I would introduce constants for the string values. What is considered clean code in TS? Something in me doesn't like the strings.

Comment: In your strings, I can see Wallet substring is common. I want to know other parts of substring Wallet. Are they static strings ? It would depend on how you want to use the constants. Could you elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: You should just use enum

Comment: @Flip You could use symbols (as they are unique) if you don't like sting constants in my opinion.

Comment: I am really just wondering if that line of code I posted is considered to be clean, or if I should use enums or constants or symbols or maybe even something else I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look into your type variable.

```
type Foo = "PrivateWallet" | "JointWallet" | "CorporationWallet" | "JuniorWallet";
```

It means that when this type variable is assigned to any js variable then it can only accept this 4 string literals type and typescript will throw an error if the string literal is not among the `Foo` type.

So, the about code is clean enough in TS if you are not accepting string literal other than Foo type.

You can make it clean more if you want but stills it depends on the use case. Here the use case would be if you want users not to put `Wallet` subString then we can use below type.

```
type Bar = "Private" | "Join" | "Junior" | "Corporation";

type Temp = `${Bar}Wallet`;
```

---

#### Using string enums

[String `enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) can also be used in place of string literals here. But still, we are using string.
According to official docs,

> Enums allow a developer to define a set of named constants. Using enums can make it easier to document intent, or create a set of distinct cases. TypeScript provides both numeric and string-based enums.

The below example is string-based enums.

```
enum Example {
  PrivateWallet = "PrivateWallet",
  JointWallet = "JointWallet",
  CorporationWallet = "CorporationWallet",
  JuniorWallet= "JuniorWallet"
}

function doSomething(ex: Example): string{

  switch(ex){
    case Example.PrivateWallet: return "Hello";
    case Example.JointWallet: return "I";
    case Example.CorporationWallet: return "am";
    case Example.JuniorWallet: return "Subrato";
    default: return "no case found";
  }
}

console.log(doSomething(Example.PrivateWallet)) // Hello
```

---

#### Using Symbols

> Better replacement of `string` is `symbol` if you want to make sure that they are always unique and immutable throughout the program.

Below is an example of using symbols in our js program.

```
const Baz = {
  PrivateWallet: Symbol('PrivateWallet'),
  JointWallet: Symbol('JointWallet'),
  JuniorWallet: Symbol('JuniorWallet'),
  CorporationWallet: Symbol('CorporationWallet')
}

function doStuff(ex: symbol){
  switch(ex){
    case Baz.CorporationWallet: return "Hello";
    case Baz.JointWallet: return "I";
    case Baz.CorporationWallet: return "am";
    case Baz.JuniorWallet: return "Subrato";
    default: return "no case found";
  }
}

console.log(doStuff(Baz.JuniorWallet)) // "Subrato"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiACgJwJYDcCGwEA6vgDZkTCpQA+aAUnNgHbCkVU32oDCcmMAMLY4LDpWp1GAVxajMErgG4AUKtCQoAIXyZkaLHkIRujZizOoGchVf6DhwUZbUbw0ACoQAtmAMABgAkAN66mAC+SsABbhAsMj5QAKIAHvh+lFAhqlBQRgRE0QYYOIUk5JKoADS5UEys7JVUJQ1s0TV1DkKYImLFKHwCPX3izdS1eTbyAtGD0wodqhHqAGZyAMbOYlAAJnAAynA+VAAWrADmABQQqQBcKemZEACUDwDOwDgsFzl17wB3bDADanG6pF45PJ5Db4d7QNIZMCUAB0BRM0QemCoMkwLDQAAkIBQ4Kg1NCoLD4Y8kai2k1OMAsTi8WgAJJkuowuEIp7IiAo7pOFyYqDY4C4-GoDKcilU3m0gULWbjZkS1moA4yABGvWApPJ0N2EFW+BkZCZYpZUpYiHlUFWcDku1lUBWK1UGzE7zgqLIcGu+yOJ2A5x+V0RzzRZQx4xeL3UXpYnx0+AAXgYofkY0VVVADiAfNrfVcAOTo3OM0svSb1CwMyQPAtFkvlnMVKs1urKxR55vFshlisdyTV2tCvUivuFgdD9vRavLNabbb4oMS1arcEfGe+yGqQHA0Hg-dynmptOC4bC-p58WSwnE-2u7nU3SX+mi+8ajmG1-Qd8r0cSdb0ZNUH2lHwX0pc9AJ7L9rTQLVdUIA0uT2E0zQtcCNVtGDqUdZ1XXdRNvV9AV-UDQ4Ny3ODbBVRl4yAA)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restrict some input to the above specified string literals, then this is a perfectly fine way, e.g. if you have a function:

```
function processWallet(wallet: "PrivateWallet" | "JointWallet" | "CorporateWallet" | "JuniorWallet", amount: number) {
  switch wallet {
    //... perform some logic based on different wallets
  }
}
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types